# SharedPreferences values are mixed up

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a mobile application. A home page welcomes the user. There is an edit button and a login button on the home page. I do not use a page for the login. I get this information from the URL, username and password edit page and I get this information with SharedPreferences on the home page and get tokens. With the token I got, I press the login button to get the data I want. The system works. But sometimes I encounter a problem. I enter the information for a user and when I press the login button, I get the information I want. But when I change user information, old token and new token sometimes get mixed up. Every time I press the login button, the information of these two users is randomly displayed. I just want to buy a token with the last entered information and receive data with that token. No error returns.
I want to fix this.I tried everything I found on the site.But could not solve the issue.

```
  class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _State createState() => _State();
    }

class _State extends State<MyApp> {
  String username = '';
  String password = '';
  String url = '';
  String token = '';

  Future<void> getToken() async {
    //...Some Information
    Map parsed = new Map();
    http
        .post(oauthUrl,
            body: map, headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth})
        .then((resp) => {
              parsed = json.decode(resp.body),
              setState(() {
                this.token = parsed["access_token"];
                _setToken(parsed["access_token"]);
              })
            })
        .catchError((err) => {this.token = "error"});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      await _getUsername().then((v) {
        setState(() {
          username = v;
        });
      });
    });
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      await _getPassword().then((v) {
        setState(() {
          password = v;
        });
      });
    });
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      await _getUrl().then((v) {
        setState(() {
          url = v;
        });
      });
    });
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      await this.getToken();
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getToken();
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My App'),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        ),
        body: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    child: Image.asset(
                  'images/my_logo.png',
                  height: 300,
                )),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Text(username ?? 'username not found.',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16)),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                  width: 20,
                ),
                Container(
                    height: 35,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        child: Text('Login'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          getToken();
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => getData()),

                          );
                        })),
                SizedBox(width: 20, height: 20),
                Container(
                    height: 35,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Text('User Infos'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => ThirdRoute()),
                          );
                        })),
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

1. If you are using SharedPreferences and everytime you change/assign the some values,do it in setState() function. In general usage , using stateful widget is best effort for this operations.You can use dummy variables to change in setState(), then your widget rebuild with your real async data.
2. Using buffer pages (like loading pages), give you enough time for getting values of async functions. I create a loading page for buffer values before widget is build.